# Keras masking - Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 10 for '{{node BCE_Last_Event/weighted_loss/Squeeze}}

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to build an RNN neural network with a custom binary-crossentropy loss function such that I the loss is computed only on the last timestep, even though the full sequence is returned.

The reason I want to do this, is that my model has a single label for each sequence, which is computed at the end. However, I want my model to be able to return the scores across the entire length of the sequence on inference, so that I can score each element in the sequence.

The custom loss function is below.

```
def BCE_Last_Event(y_true, y_pred):
    
    y_last_pred = tf.expand_dims(y_pred[:, -1], -1)
    y_last_true = y_true

    return tf.keras.metrics.binary_crossentropy(y_last_true, y_last_pred, axis=-1)
```

I now create a simple RNN with an embedding layer for categorical features which will be padded with 0s.

```
samples, timesteps, features = 2000, 10, 1
inputs_1 = np.random.randint(1, 50, [samples, timesteps, features]).astype(np.float32)
labels = np.random.randint(0, 2, [samples, 1])
cat_feats = ["cat_feat_" + str(x) for x in range(1)]


categorical_inputs = {tensorName: (Input(shape=(None,), name=tensorName))
                        for tensorName in cat_feats}

inputs = [i for i in categorical_inputs.values()]
        


# Embeddings
emb = Embedding(input_dim=int(50),
                            output_dim=20,
                            input_length=(None,),
                            mask_zero=False,
                            name="cat_feat_0" + "_emb")(categorical_inputs["cat_feat_0"])


gru = GRU(32,
          activation="tanh",
          dropout=0,
          recurrent_dropout=0,
          go_backwards=False,
          return_sequences=True,
          name="gru_cat")(emb)


y = Dense(10, activation = "tanh")(gru)
y = Dropout(0.4)(y)
y = Dense(1, activation = "sigmoid")(y)

model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=y)

metrics = ["accuracy"]
model.compile(loss=BCE_Last_Event,
                          optimizer=Adam(beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999),
                          metrics=metrics)
```

When I fit the model, it learns as expected with the loss being computed only on the last timestep for the predicted values, so as to not be influenced by previous timesteps (i.e., a many-to-one loss with a many-to-many inference behavior).

```
model.fit(inputs_1, labels, steps_per_epoch=30, epochs=1, verbose=1)
```

However, when I set `mask_zero=True` in the Embedding layer, I get the following error.

```
ValueError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 10 for '{{node BCE_Last_Event/weighted_loss/Squeeze}} = Squeeze[T=DT_FLOAT, squeeze_dims=[-1]](Cast)' with input shapes: [?,10].
```

Why is that? How can I modify my custom loss function to work with the masking layer?

Furthermore, what if I also have a numerical vector padded with a different value (say -999) and wish to mask and concatenate this to the output of the embedding layer before the GRU. How would the masking work then for the custom loss function? Finally, does masking hold in inference time? Would it predict null scores or repeat the scores from the previous timestep?

I'm on tensorflow 2.9.1.